# Compare timpestamps with NULL timestamps in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table that have column `last_crawled_article_at timestamp default NULL`

I've noticed a problem when I try to make update with `WHERE` clause like:

```
UPDATE feed
    SET last_crawled_article_at=?, last_captured_id=?
    WHERE
        feed = ? AND
        last_crawled_article_at < ?
```

If `last_crawled_article_at` is `NULL` the update never success due don't have any row that contains `last_crawled_article_at` greater than `NULL`.

If I have the table with one entry with timestamp `NULL` and I do the next query:

```
SELCT FROM feed WHERE last_crawled_article_at < '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
```

The Mysql don't return anything.

The way I solved this behaviour is adding `last_crawled_article_at` to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

My question is, why `lt` timestamp range query doesn't returns entries with `NULL` value?

It's advised in some way to not use `timestamp` fields with `NULL` as default?

Comment: because `null` check is done by `is null`

Comment: Why de negative? It's the question not clear or spammy?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I might guess that it's because knowing how `null`s compare is a basic feature of using SQL and probably doesn't make for useful questions.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer , sometimes feels like you have to know everything before questioning something! (I tried it with different approach and know how to solve it, only asked it for curiosity to know the difference of timestamp `NULL` and timestamp `0000-00-00 00:00:00`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you also want to update null values, you have to add `or last_crawled_article_at is null`

```
UPDATE feed
    SET last_crawled_article_at=?, last_captured_id=?
    WHERE
        feed = ? AND
        (last_crawled_article_at < ? or last_crawled_article_at is null)
```